# JQuery on() method, combine multi class and event handlers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am looking one solution for combine multi selectors and different event handlers for execute my funcion.

My question: i have a form with all data that pass to php by ajax. Now i send it by submit input, and .on 'submit' event, but i need execute it also by another event click with another class, example an checkbox.

Inside form have class .formdataaj and inside an checkbox called .checkbox_ajx (i use it like switch for pass var 1 or 0 to php, activate or disactivate my posts)

my code:

```
$('.formdataaj').each(function(){
        $(this).on('submit',function(e){
        var className=$(this);
        e.preventDefault();
        var form_data = new FormData(this);
        //console.log(...form_data);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'php/extra_update.php',
            data: form_data,
            processData:false,
            contentType:false,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);
                
                //get parse json data
                var jsondata = $.parseJSON(data);
                console.log(jsondata);
                
            }

        })
        
    })
    })
```

Thank you

Comment: Put the code in a named function. Then call that function from both the submit handler and the click handler.

Comment: thank you for reply @barmar, but i get error Failed to construct 'FormData'. With submit function work, but by click i get error.  Work partially if i put  var form_data = new FormData(this); above submit and click handler function, but don't pass updated data.

Comment: You'll need to pass `this` as an argument to the function when you call it from the handler.

Comment: Or you can use `e.target`

Comment: thank you, work! an example for e.target?

Comment: `$(".formdataaj").submit(function(e) { namedFunction(e.target); }`